# Web service: how WSDL works

Tags: web-services

Whenever I am creating a soap client in the eclipse, I put in WSDL of that service. After this activity, it fetches all the .class files.

Could you please help me understand, why these .class files are being created, are we importing the service logic into the client or these class files are just interfaces created on parsing the WSDL?
please help me understand how client program parse the WSDL file?